# How can I alter this ML.NET code to input data through the console instead

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I'm following a tutorial which has given me this sample code. I want to alter it so the user inputs the data through the console rather than in the code but I'm unsure how to, any ideas?

```
using MyMLApp;
// Add input data

var sampleData = new SentimentModel.ModelInput()
{
    Col0 = "Will never go here again!"
};

// Load model and predict output of sample data
var result = SentimentModel.Predict(sampleData);

// If Prediction is 1, sentiment is "Positive"; otherwise, sentiment is "Negative"
string sentiment = result.Prediction == 1 ? "Positive" : "Negative";
Console.WriteLine($"Text: {sampleData.Col0}\nSentiment: {sentiment}");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Console.ReadLine(). Optionally handle empty input in your code.

```
string? input = Console.ReadLine();
var sampleData = new SentimentModel.ModelInput()
{
    Col0 = input
};
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you this works, I was trying it without the ? after string which is why it wouldn't work for me :)